# Send Multitext From Android to API

Tags: php, android, api, android-edittext

I have created a "contact us form" in android that uses PHP Api to send me an email. For example, In the EditText message I type:

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
```

When I receive the email it shows this:

```
This is line 1\nThis is line 2\n
```

Code to send email:

```
         String myURL = myDomain+myPHPDir+"sendMessageFromContactUs.php?pMyUsername="+myUsername
             +"&pName="+strName
             +"&pEmail="+strEmail
             +"&pMessage="+strMessage
             ;
     String noSpace = myURL.replaceAll(" ","%20").replaceAll("\n", "%0A");
     task.execute(new String[] {noSpace});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the following way.

ON PHP:

- First of all `"\n" or "\r\n"` did not work for me, it printed on the same line.
- Secondly `"<br>"` worked, it printed characters on new line.

I then read up a bit on "A Complete Guide to URL Escape Characters" from the source below:

```
https://www.werockyourweb.com/url-escape-characters/
```

So:

```
for <br> this < is %3C AND this > is %3E THEREFORE <br> becomes %3Cbr%3E
```

ON ANDROID:

I changed from (didn't work):

```
String noSpace = myURL.replaceAll(" ","%20").replaceAll("\n","%0A");
```

To (working):

```
String noSpace = myURL.replaceAll(" ","%20").replaceAll("\n","%3Cbr%3E");
```

Now I am able to write paragraphs in EditText and Outlook will show them correctly.

Cheers!

UPDATE: (Just to add)

The way in which these characters are interpreted (which I later learned and the reason for sharing this update) are because of the header used in the php script that sends mail: (the characters you use when you set a $header with a text/html content-type (as seen in code below) will use HTML (No longer PHP) escape characters)

```
$headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\";
```